# C++:QX11EmbedContainer not working on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, embed, x11, qx11embedcontainer

Given below is the code that I have written for opening VLC from Qt. I want to use the QX11EmbedContainer so that I can use it to "contain" VLC.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QX11EmbedContainer>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString prog="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/... .exe";
    QProcess *proc=new QProcess();
    proc->start(prog);
    return a.exec();
}
```

On adding the header file **QX11EmbedContainer** I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HA\main.cpp:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QX11EmbedContainer': No such file or directory
```

Is QX11EmbedContainer an add-on? If not then where am I going wrong?

Comment: Windows Qt normally comes without X11 support, and you don't want to use X11 on Windows anyway.

Comment: @n.m. So what do I use then?

Comment: I have no idea. Probaably QFrame. See [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt/).